# Деплой проекта на GitHub Pages

Tags: nuxt.js

У меня вот есть проект, делал по тутору akella: https://github.com/merrymaker14/vuegl
Решил залить на GitHub Pages.
https://merrymaker14.github.io/vuegl

Но он по страницам нормально не переходит, хотя вроде все настроил. Почему?

nuxt.config.js:

```
import pkg from './package'

/* nuxt.config.js */
// only add `router.base = '/<repository-name>/'` if `DEPLOY_ENV` is `GH_PAGES`
const routerBase = process.env.DEPLOY_ENV === 'GH_PAGES' ? {
  router: {
    base: '/vuegl/'
  }
} : {}

export default {
  mode: 'universal',

  /*
  ** Headers of the page
  */
  head: {
    title: pkg.name,
    meta: [
      { charset: 'utf-8' },
      { name: 'viewport', content: 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1' },
      { hid: 'description', name: 'description', content: pkg.description }
    ],
    link: [
      { rel: 'icon', type: 'image/x-icon', href: '/favicon.ico' }
    ]
  },

  /*
  ** Customize the progress-bar color
  */
  loading: { color: '#fff' },

  ...routerBase,

  router: {
     middleware: 'pages',
     //base: '/examples/vuegl/'
  },

  /*
  ** Global CSS
  */
  css: [
  ],

  /*
  ** Plugins to load before mounting the App
  */
  plugins: [
  ],

  /*
  ** Nuxt.js modules
  */
  modules: [
  ],

  /*
  ** Build configuration
  */
  build: {
    /*
    ** You can extend webpack config here
    */
    extend(config, ctx) {
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<template>
    <div class="navigation">
    <nuxt-link to="/">Homepage</nuxt-link>
    <nuxt-link to="/about">About</nuxt-link>
    <nuxt-link to="/another">another</nuxt-link>
    </div>
</template>
```

У вас ссылки относительные.

Вам надо ссылки явно указать, а то относительные ссылки на GHPages не работают.

```
<template>
    <div class="navigation">
    <nuxt-link to="https://merrymaker14.github.io/vuegl/">Homepage</nuxt-link>
    <nuxt-link to="https://merrymaker14.github.io/vuegl/about">About</nuxt-link>
    <nuxt-link to="https://merrymaker14.github.io/vuegl/another">another</nuxt-link>
    </div>
</template>
```

Comment: Не, так не работает, он прибавляет, становится что-то вроде: https://merrymaker14.github.io/vuegl/https://merrymaker14.github.io/vuegl/about"

Comment: Окей тогда, учитывая то что старые ссылки переводят на merrymaker.github.io поставьте тогда /vuegl, /vuelgl/about и так далее.